# Сортировка рваного массива

Tags: c#, массивы, сортировка

То, что у меня получилось, сортирует элементы массива в строках. Мне нужно, чтобы сортировались все элементы массива.
Например,

```
6 1 2 3
4 9 8
7 5 0

0 1 2 3 
4 5 6 
7 8 9  

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Array before sort:");
            int[][] jagged = new int[5][];//объявление рваного массива: количество строк и количество элементов внутри
            jagged[0] = new int[6];
            jagged[1] = new int[2];
            jagged[2] = new int[4];
            jagged[3] = new int[9];
            jagged[4] = new int[5];

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < jagged[i].Length; j++)//заполнение массива случайными числами и вывод их на экран
                {
                    jagged[i][j] = rand.Next(-15, 15);
                    Console.Write(jagged[i][j] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Array after sort:");
            for (int i = 0; i < jagged.Length; i++)

            {
                Array.Sort(jagged[i]);

            }
            Array.Sort(jagged, (x, y) => x.Length.CompareTo(y.Length));
            for (int i = 0; i < jagged.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < jagged[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(jagged[i][j]+" ");

                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: Запишите все в 1 массив (я бы использовал список List<int> и ф-ю AddRange ), отсортируйте и верните в исчодный массив

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пишем метод для печати массива

```
void PrintArray(int[][] source)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < source[i].Length; j++)
            Console.Write($"{source[i][j]} ");
        Console.WriteLine();
    }   
}
```

Потом метод для сортировки

```
void SortJagged(int[][] source)
{
    var len = source.Sum(x=>x.Length);
    var arr = new int[len];

    int ind = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<source.Length; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<source[i].Length; j++)
            arr[ind++]=source[i][j];

    Array.Sort(arr);

    ind = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < source[i].Length; j++)
            source[i][j] = arr[ind++];
}
```

Потом убираем из вашего кода всё ненужное

```
Random rand = new Random();
int[][] jagged = new int[5][];//объявление рваного массива: количество строк и количество элементов внутри
jagged[0] = new int[6];
jagged[1] = new int[2];
jagged[2] = new int[4];
jagged[3] = new int[9];
jagged[4] = new int[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < jagged[i].Length; j++)//заполнение массива случайными числами и вывод их на экран       
        jagged[i][j] = rand.Next(-15, 15);

Console.WriteLine("Before sorting");
PrintArray(jagged);

SortJagged(jagged);

Console.WriteLine("After sorting");
PrintArray(jagged);
```

Получаем вывод

```
Before sorting
14 12 -9 -5 13 -8 
-3 -7 
1 7 -12 -4 
5 4 5 -9 -13 14 -10 -5 13 
1 -10 11 14 -3 
After sorting
-13 -12 -10 -10 -9 -9 
-8 -7 
-5 -5 -4 -3 
-3 1 1 4 5 5 7 11 12 
13 13 14 14 14
```